# Is it possible to load and display large(8296 x 14740 pix) images in python?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, tiff

I need my python script to load and display large(35 MB - 8296 pix x 14740 pix) image in tiff format.
I have tried with openCV:

```
img = cv2.imread("filename.tif",-1)
cv2.namedWindow('map',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('map',img)
```

and I got:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)
in cv::imshow, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261

cv2.error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261:
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

I also tried with matplotlib:

```
img = cv2.imread("filename.tif",-1)
pyplot.imshow(img)
pyplot.show()
```

and I got:

```
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

How to load and display such a file?

Comment: Could you upload an example of such an image somewhere?

Comment: File added to main post

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib provides a convenience function to load images:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('filename.tif')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: And it results in:
Image size (122283040 pixels) exceeds limit of 89478485 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.  DecompressionBombWarning.

MemoryError

Comment: Yes, I get this as a warning. But the code still runs

Comment: And the image is displaying? On my side it end with MemoryError and nothing more happens

Comment: It takes some seconds to load the data and display it. But the image is displayed just fine

Comment: I guess you geto only DecompressionBombWarning but i get also a MemoryError. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Well the `MemoryError` tells you that you dont have enough memory. You could free some by closing other programs first. But if you only want to display the image, I would suggest to downscale it first.

Comment: Can't do it. There is like 800 of images like this. Meaby if I try using image pyramids before displaying it.

Comment: What can't you do? Isn't downscaling the same as using pyramids?

Comment: You are right. I tought that You ask me to make this image smaller somwhere else and then try to display it. Right now i have no idea how to downscale it so i think that the question is over.

Comment: If you are using linux you could use something like: `convert filename.tif  -resize 20% filename_smaller.tif`

Answer (score 0):

I opened it using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('filename.tiff')
img.show()
```

I get `DecompressionBombWarning` but it opens after few seconds.